# How to get Dropbox to sync changes inside a symlinked directory?

Tags: dropbox, symbolic-link, window

On Win 7 I have a symbolic link from inside the Dropbox pointing to an external directory which I'd like to sync.

Upon the initial sym-linking and whenever restarting the Dropbox program, the sync works properly. However, when some files get added/removed/changed inside the external directory, Dropbox doesn't sync them. Instead, all such files instantly appear in Explorer with the green checkmark icon *as if* they were synced, but they are never uploaded (as can be evidenced by browsing the dropbox via the web interface , or by the failure to copy a sharing link to a file due to the file being "not uploaded".)

I guess that the trigger for changes inside that external dir somehow doesn't reach the dropbox process. Is there any way to work around this so that it syncs properly?